# select query help update

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below select query for daily data, how do I amend to make it pull the full month of data

```
select *
from BAU_SDT_INV_USER
where trunc(CHECKED_DATE) = to_date('2018/12/18', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the full month in Oracle:

```
where checked_date >= date '2018-12-01' and
      checked_date < date '2019-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
select * from BAU_SDT_INV_USER 
where CHECKED_DATE >= to_date('2018/12/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
  and CHECKED_DATE < to_date('2019/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from BAU_SDT_INV_USER
where trunc(CHECKED_DATE) BETWEEN to_date('2018/12/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD')  
  AND to_date('2018/12/31', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

More Index Friendly approach would be

```
select *
from BAU_SDT_INV_USER
where CHECKED_DATE between ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1) and sysdate
```

**EDIT** Please note that between clause is inclusive. you can also use

```
select *
from BAU_SDT_INV_USER
where CHECKED_DATE >= ADD_MONTHS(to_date(:inputDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), -1)  
  and CHECKED_DATE < TO_DATE(:input_Date,'YYYY/MM/DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not a key point for your query, just `trunc` by month on both ends of the comparison :

```
select *
from BAU_SDT_INV_USER
where trunc(CHECKED_DATE, 'mm') = trunc( to_date('2018/12/18', 'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'mm')
```

Comment: Correct, but not index-friendly.

Comment: @TheImpaler : Yes. I updated my post to notify that.